# SystemVerilog: selecting bits without storing calculation in variable

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Is there really no way to select bits straight from a calculation without giving them a name and then selecting the bits from the name in SystemVerilog?

```
module testbench;
  logic signed [7:0] x = 8'b11100000;
  logic signed [7:0] y = 8'b00010100;
  logic [15:0] z;
  initial begin
    z = x*y;
    $display("%b", z[14:7]); // :)
    //$display("%b", (15'(x*y))[14:7]); // :(
    //$display("%b", 15'(x*y)[14:7]); // :(
    //$display("%b", {15'(x*y)}[14:7]); // :(
    //none of the above 3 works
  end
endmodule
```

Context: I want to non-blockingly assign the 14:7 bits of the product of two signed 8 bit numbers to another 8 bit number without waiting for the next clock cycle:

```
z <= 15'(x*y)[14:7];
```

Comment: Update: {15'(x*y)}[14:7]) works in ModelSim/Questa as per dave_59's answer

Answer (score 1):

So close , use a concatenation

`Z <= {x*y}[14:7]`

Comment: This short answer was flagged as LQ. Even if it is correct the servers will flag this stuff every time. I am not going to delete it because it may be correct, but please expand future answers so they don't get an LQ flag.

Comment: What simulator are you using that will accept that? Synopsys VCS says (paraphrasing - can't access simulators right now) "Feature not yet implemented". Cadence Incisive and Aldec Riviera Pro also complain about it.

Comment: I’m using Modelsim/Questa. “Not yet implemented” means the syntax is correct, but they haven’t implemented the feature yet.

Comment: Just tried Questa and sure enough it works if you cast it to 15 bits inside the concatenation brackets. Thanks Dave.